# How can I plot this piecewise function in python?

Tags: python

[Piecewise function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxaIb.png)

I don't know how to plot it

Comment: What have you tried so far? What plotting package are you using?

Comment: before plotting it you will need to implement it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `matplotlib`'s `pyplot` package. It has very user-friendly functions for plotting. This is my approach to plotting this piecewise function:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# boundaries
xmin = -3
xmax = 3

N = 1001 # resolution of points between [xmin, xmax]

# create x axis and empty y array
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, N)
y = np.zeros(N)

# apply the piecewise operations:
y[x<0] = np.sin(x[x<0])
y[(0<x) & (x<1)] = np.arctan(x[(0<x) & (x<1)])
y[1<x] = np.pi*x[1<x]**3/4

# plot
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I used array slicing with the piecewise conditions to edit the `y` array before plotting. Hope this helps!